# How to hide Bars from chart in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I need to hide bars from Charts based on a condition in SSRS.

For example,

I am creating chart to display ranks of the students and I wanted to hide bars for the students whose rank > 4 and have to display the text as 'N/A'. 
[Highlighted bar in the image should be hidden and the 'N/A' text alone has to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asdbm.png)

Can anyone share the ideas to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow I found answer for myself.

We can set the expression in Sereis properties like below (right click the appropriate legend's series properties in chart data ) to hide the bar:

IIF(Fields!Studrank.Value > 5 ,0, Sum(Fields!No_of_Accounts.Value) )-- To hide bar

Set Below expression under Number tab in Series Label Properties to display the text as "N/A" :

IIF(Fields!Studrank.Value > 5 ,"N/A",Fields!Studrank.Value) -- To display "N/A"